# Program ends at while loop

Tags: python

```
import random


dice1=random.randint (1,6)
dice2=random.randint (1,6)


strengthone = int(input ("Player 1, between 1 and 10 What do you want your characters strength to be? Higher is not always better."))
skillone = int(input ("Player 1, between 1 and 10 What do you want your characters skill to be? Higher is not always better."))

if strengthone > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")
if skillone > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value.")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")

strengthtwo = int(input ("Player 2, between 1 and 10 what do you want your characters strength to be? Higher is not always better."))
skilltwo = int(input ("Player 2, between 1 and 10 what do you want your characters skill to be? Higher is not always better."))

if strengthtwo > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value.")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")
if skillone > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value.")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")

strengthmod = strengthone - strengthtwo
skillmod = skillone - skilltwo
strengthmodone = strengthone - strengthtwo
skillmodone = skillone - skilltwo
strengthmodtwo = strengthone - strengthtwo
skillmodtwo = skillone - skilltwo

print ("Player 1, you rolled a", str(dice1))
print ("Player 2, you rolled a", str(dice2))

while True:
    if dice1 == dice2:
        print ("")
    if dice1 > dice2:
        strengthmodone = strengthmod + strengthone
        strengthmodone = strengthmod + strengthone
    if dice2 > dice1:
        strengthmodtwo = strengthmod + strengthtwo
        skillmodtwo = skillmod + skilltwo
    if dice1 < dice2:
        strengthmodone = strengthmod - strengthone
        skillmodone= skillmod - skillone
    if dice2 < dice1:
        strengthmodtwo = strengthmod - strengthtwo
        skillmodtwo = skillmod - skilltwo
    break
    if strengthmodone == 0:
        print ("Player one dies, well done player two. You win!")
    if strengthmodtwo == 0:
        print ("Player two dies, well done player one. You win!")
    if strengthmodone== 0:
        print ("Player one dies, well done player two. You win!")
    if strengthmodtwo == 0:
        print ("Player two dies, well done player one. You win!")
```

The program is just ending when it reaches the while loop. I have no idea why and how to fix this, any ideas? And i'm still unsure on how even to use loops properly, so i may be using it completely wrong, please let me know what im doing wrong and how to fix this.

Comment: Question already answered, but also note the `if dice2 > dice1:` and `if dice1 < dice2:`...

Comment: @tobias_k: Those are fine; both `if` statements are indeed `True` but affect either player one or player two scores. Yes, they can be combined but are not the cause of any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `break` in your `while True:` loop that is *always* executed:

```
while True:
    if dice1 == dice2:
        # [ ... ]
    # [ ... ]
    # more `if` statements
    # [ ... ]
    if dice2 < dice1:
        # [ ... ]
    break
```

Remove it or move it into an `if` statement.

Your next problem is that you never re-roll the dice in your loop. You'll need to keep assigning new random values to `dice1` and `dice2` for each round of the game.

Comment: Done that, but now i just have an infinite loop. I need one of the players' strength to hit 0 at some point so that they die

Comment: @user2768659: You never re-roll the dice, so that isn't that big a surprise.